# How can I use Graphics.Dispose / Using Statements

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to improve the performance of my Winform application, and I found that I wasn't disposing graphics objects and instead relying on garbage collection, how can I implement the `Graphics.Dispose` method into my paint event?

```
public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bigImage, scrollX, scrollY);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(smallImage, peanutHitboxX, peanutHitboxY);
}
```

The image `bigImage` is an image bigger than the screen, and constantly moving. I want to dispose the graphics from it but when I change the code to this:

```
public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bigImage, scrollX, scrollY);
   e.Graphics.Dispose();
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(smallImage, peanutHitboxX, peanutHitboxY);
}
```

It says that `smallImage` isn't valid, and moving `e.Graphics.Dispose();` to the bottom returns an error in an entirely different file used by winforms

How do I just dispose `bigImage` without messing up things with `smallImage`?

Comment: Don't dispose graphic objects you didn't create.  You didn't create the `e.Graphics` object from the Paint event, so it's not your responsibility.

Comment: You didn't create the graphics object so you are not responsible for it and should not dispose it. The Form created it and called the event with it might still do something with it after the event so don't dispose.

Comment: Also you seem to have a missunderstood what the paint event does. It is called regularly every time a repaint is needed. Minimizing, maximizing or moving between monitors or even (on older Windows versions) simply moving other forms over this one everytime a (re)paint event is needed. If you have disposed the bitmap somehow (not possible) it could not be repainted you app would be broken.